# Swift and relational database

Tags: sql-server, swift, oracle, macos

Is there a way in swift (5) to access a relational database? (SQL Server or Oracle)
like JDBC for Java or ADO for .NET?

A code example will be welcome.

Comment: for MacOs (sorry to forget that)

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add more details and extra tags.

Comment: There are 3rd party libraries, google is your friend

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

There is a native client for SQL Server on GitHub: https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient/

**Remarks:**

Recently, connecting clients directly to a DB server is considered to be a very bad practice, especially for security reasons.

Prepare an API server and construct RESTful services which work for you app. You may choose any languages to implement the APIs.
(My favorite way to construct RESTful services for now is using ASP.NET MVC, but not many clients listen to my proposal...
One of my clients chose Java and Ruby, and another, PHP.)

And your app can use many HTTP-based communication classes and methods. Most of them are easily accessible from Swift.

Comment: REstAPI is not the best way to develop a tool to manage database :)

Comment: @OlivierPieri nowhere does it say _manage_ in the question.